# remove part of string in Perl

Tags: perl

```
my $input1 = "hours";
my $input2 = "Total hours";
my ($matching_key) = grep { /$input2/ } $input1;
print "Matching key :: $matching_key";
```

What I want is to strip "Total" from $input2 and assign it back to input2 so my grep line will match. how can I strip that word ?

Answer (score 11):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you want

```
$input2 =~ s/Total //;
```

However, you're also misusing `grep()`; it returns an array of elements in its second parameter (which should also be a list) which match the pattern given in the first parameter. While it will in fact return "hours" in scalar context they way you're using it, this is pretty much coincidental.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. basically as a user, I will be inputting "hours". I assign $input2 after logging into a machine and getting information. $input2 will always have "Total hours" but I dont want the user to input as "Total hours" but rather just hours. Hence , I want to strip out "Total" so $input2 will match $input1.

Answer (score 6):

I am not sure that I understand fully your question, anyway you can strip Total like this:

```
$input2 =~ s/Total //;
```

after this $input2 will have the value `"hours"`.

I don't understand fully the "assign it back to input2 so my grep line will match" part...

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure exactly what you're asking, but if you want `$input2` to be 'Total', try

```
$input2 =~ s/ hours//;
```

or

```
$input2 = substr $input2, 0, 5;
```

Similarly, if you want `$input2` to be 'hours', try

```
$input2 =~ s/Total //;
```

or

```
$input2 = substr $input2, 6;
```

Answer (score 0):

Like so

```
my $input1 = "hours"; 
my $input2 = "Total hours";
$input2 =~ m/($input1)/;
print "Matching key : $1\n";
```